# Use existing network in docker-compose: service 'networks' must be a mapping not an array

Tags: networking, docker

I want to use the existing network "nextcloudpi":

```
$ sudo docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                               DRIVER    SCOPE
bc60ac79af99   bridge                             bridge    local
e374ccc22ff4   host                               host      local
6822ac7b54c6   ncp_reverse_proxy_bc_nextcloudpi   bridge    local
dc749eca4598   ncp_reverse_proxy_nextcloudpi      bridge    local
6a83b3f6e623   nextcloudpi                        bridge    local
eeb4fc6c4f16   none                               null      local
79949d81c193   overleaf_default                   bridge    local
```

I get the error:

> In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'networks' must be a mapping
> not an array

```
version: '2.2'


networks:
  nextcloudpi:
    external: true


services:
    sharelatex:
        restart: always
        # Server Pro users:
        # image: quay.io/sharelatex/sharelatex-pro
        image: sharelatex/sharelatex
        container_name: sharelatex
        depends_on:
            mongo:
                condition: service_healthy
            redis:
                condition: service_started
        ports:
            - 83:80
        links:
            - mongo
            - redis
        networks:
           - nextcloudpi
```

Comment: Try to add another space in front of `- nextcloudpi` and see if that helps. `yaml` files must have the correct indentation.

Comment: @ArturMeinild is correct unless that is a copy/paste error. There is a space lacking. Otherwise I would expect the `-` to be the isue: the notice means it is expecting  a key:value pair; those are without a `-`. `-` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

This file is working as expected:

```
version: '2.2'
  

services:
    sharelatex:
        restart: always
        # Server Pro users:
        # image: quay.io/sharelatex/sharelatex-pro
        image: sharelatex/sharelatex
        container_name: sharelatex
        depends_on:
            mongo:
                condition: service_healthy
            redis:
                condition: service_started
        ports:
            - 83:80
        links:
            - mongo
            - redis
        

networks:
  default:
    name: nextcloudpi
    external: true
```